# Run a single file in pytest that is a module in a PEP 420 implicit namespace package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a file `dir/subdir/module.py` using relative imports so that

```
python3 dir/subdir/module.py
```

fails with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.test_forward'; '__main__' is not a package
```

but

```
python3 -m dir.subdir.module
```

runs.

Unsurprisingly,

```
python3 -m pytest dir/subdir/module.py
pytest dir/subdir/module.py
```

fail as well. Can I run this module's tests from pytest (without changing it)?

Of course, I've looked at [How to test single file under pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833327/how-to-test-single-file-under-pytest) and https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdline, but failed to find an answer.

Here is a minimal reproducing example:

File `proj/main.py`:

```
def func():
    return 1
```

File `proj/tests.py`:

```
from .main import func

def test_func():
    assert func() == 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_func()
```

Note that I omitted `__init__.py` in `proj` as per [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

```
(venv) romanov@k9-09:~/temp$ python3 -m proj.tests
(venv) romanov@k9-09:~/temp$
```

Tests run and pass (if I change `test_func` to fail, I get the expected result).

```
(venv) romanov@k9-09:~/temp$ python3 proj/tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proj/tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .main import func
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

With pytest:

```
(venv) romanov@k9-09:~/temp$ pytest proj/tests.py
============================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
hypothesis profile 'default' -> database=DirectoryBasedExampleDatabase('/home/romanov/temp/.hypothesis/examples')
rootdir: /home/romanov/temp, inifile:
plugins: hypothesis-4.0.1
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting proj/tests.py _______________________________________________________________________________________
proj/tests.py:1: in <module>
    from .main import func
E   SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================================================== 1 error in 0.09 seconds ===========================================================================================
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't *fully* reproduce the problem; here `pytest --pyargs proj.tests` suggested in ivan_pozdeev's answer says `ERROR: file or package not found: proj.tests (missing __init__.py?)` and adding empty `proj/__init__.py` lets it run.

Comment: I guess you're trying to run as a test the main file and not a test file. Could you edit the question, adding all the import of the test file?

Comment: @pittix The file contains tests, its `if __name__ == '__main__'` section just calls the test functions. I was trying to run it under pytest to get better error messages. The file is also part of a large project. I've tried to make a smaller reproducing example, but didn't succeed completely (see the edit).

Comment: Your `test_func` is not a Python `unittest` test so pytest won't find it AFAIK.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It will, because it starts with `test_`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery (or just look at the starting example in https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev And it does find and run `test_func` if `proj/__init__.py` is added, as mentioned at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Pytest a project using PEP 420 namespace packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174130/how-do-i-pytest-a-project-using-pep-420-namespace-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-as-part-of-application-code:

> You can use Python3 namespace packages (PEP420) for your application but pytest will still perform test package name discovery based on the presence of `__init__.py` files. If you use one of the two recommended file system layouts above but leave away the `__init__.py` files from your directories it should just work on Python3.3 and above. **From “inlined tests”, however, you will need to use absolute imports for getting at your application code.**

So my desired combination isn't possible without adding `__init__.py` files.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Usage and Invocations — pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html):

> ### Run tests from packages
>
> ```
> pytest --pyargs pkg.testing
> ```
>
> This will import `pkg.testing` and use its filesystem location to find
>   and run tests from.

```
In [9]: !ls -R t
t:
__init__.py  main.py  tests.py

In [10]: pwd
Out[10]: u'c:\\Users\\Sasha\\Desktop'

In [7]: os.environ['PYTHONPATH']=r'c:\Users\Sasha\Desktop'

In [8]: !pytest --pyargs t.tests
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.15+, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: c:\Users\Sasha\Desktop, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.15.0, mock-1.5.0, instafail-0.3.0
collected 1 items

t\tests.py .

========================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

If you omit `__init__.py` as per PEP 420, `pytest` becomes confused because the core premise of its logic is to search the subtree for test files and import them. Without `__init__.py`, it has no way to find out if it should import files as subpackages or as standalone modules.

Comment: Didn't see it, but I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when trying.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov WFM for the scenario you described, see update.

Comment: In the scenario I described, `__init__.py` is in the parent directory (or absent), not in the same directory where `main.py` and `tests.py` are. (As far as I understand, this is only allowed since Python 3.3: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you said: _"empty `__init__.py`"_, not "omitted `__init__.py` as per PEP 420".

Comment: Yes, empty `__init__.py` _in the parent directory_: `__init__.py`, `proj/main.py`, and `proj/tests.py`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov there's absolutely no reason to place `__init__.py` in the parent directory because you are not using the parent directory as a package in your example -- that file is never used. So I assumed that you omitted the path for brevity. Because inaccurate descriptions are common on this site, I assume probable rather than extremily improbable things. Extremily strange and improbable details of your setup is something that you specifically mention and emphasize.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the mention of `__init__.py`.